# Eloquent model - replace property value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In a `Eloquent` model, the corresponding table has a numeric column `status`, I have to replace the numeric value with a string.
Currently I do it using a method. That method returns the corresponding `text` from a predefined array.

Is there any way to replace the numeric value with text in constructor or somewhere else so that I don't need to call a method each time?

It may be helpful: It is a laravel project.

Comment: You can make use of mutators : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Laravel Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) will serve the purpose Best here as they are call when you instantiate the object of model

For Eg:

Lets say you have a Post Table with attributes as
**[ id,name,description,author_id and status ]**

lets say you want to show **"active" text for status 1** and **"inactive" for status 2** 
So, You can:

1) create an status associative array on your model

```
$statuses = [1=>'active',2=>'inactive'];
```

2) use mutator to respond:

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value){
 return $this->statuses[$value];
}
```

3) To test try :

```
  Posts::find(1)->toArray();
```

should output all status updated. as 1 shown as active and 2 inactive.

Comment: I am using this. But won't the mutator will be called for each access? I just want something so that the text replaces the number. So that the mutator will not be called each time.

Comment: yes it will..i added this solution based on the question you have asked..also, is that case when would you expect the output to be formatted?

Comment: if you want to apply it to say some specific routes a middlware could do the trick..however its not intended for that purpose..or else you can create a formatter class that will spit the output as per the requirement and generalize it for any other use as well